# Meaning of "auf geht's" and "los geht's"

Tags: meaning, word-usage, difference

Do "Los geht's" and "Auf geht's" mean "let's go"?

> Willst du ins Kino? Los geht's/ auf geht's!

Comment: Simple answer: yes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes they do mean "let's go" and you can answer "Willst du ins Kino gehen?" with "Los geht's". But "Ja gerne" would be the more common answer.

Comment: I heard this expression in a song of the same title by die Fanta Vier and Los geht' from Ramsi Aliani's song ' Schlagalarm'. I thought they all meant ' Let's go'.

Comment: Auf geht's von den Fantastischen 4

Comment: Well, there's a big difference between language in music and actually spoken language.

Comment: *"Los geht's" is more common than "Auf geht's"* I doubt it. Probably depends on audience, region, etc.

Comment: Is there a phrase one would be more likely to use for "let's go" (to the movies)?

Comment: And what does the 's stand for?

Answer (score 1):

"Los geht's" is more akin to "Let's go", whereas "Auf geht's" is more akin to "Here we go".

Comment: I don't see this difference. Any references or examples for that?